# fpdf en php fatal error Error en PHP Ouput

Tags: php, mysql, fpdf

Al programar en php y considerar fpf me maca el siguuiente error:

Notice: Undefined index: nombres in C:\xampp\htdocs\F\Reportes\reporte.php on line 21

Notice: Undefined index: nombres in C:\xampp\htdocs\F\Reportes\reporte.php on line 21

Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: FPDF error: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file in C:\xampp\fpdf182\fpdf182\fpdf.php:271 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\fpdf182\fpdf182\fpdf.php(1060): FPDF->Error('Some data has a...') #1 C:\xampp\fpdf182\fpdf182\fpdf.php(999): FPDF->_checkoutput() #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\F\Reportes\reporte.php(23): FPDF->Output() #3 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\fpdf182\fpdf182\fpdf.php on line 271

```
<?php
    include 'plantilla.php';
    require 'conexion.php';
    
    $query = "SELECT * FROM posts";
    $resultado = $mysqli->query($query);
    
    $pdf = new PDF();  //creacion de objeto
      
    $pdf->AliasNbPages();
    $pdf->AddPage();    
    $pdf->SetFillColor(232,232,232);
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',12);
    $pdf->Cell(20,6,'id',1,0,'C',0);
    $pdf->Cell(40,6,'nombres',1,0,'C',0);   
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',10);
    
    while($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc())
    {
        $pdf->Cell(20,6,utf8_decode($row['id']),1,0,'C',0);
        $pdf->Cell(40,6,utf8_decode($row['nombres']),1,0,'C',0);
    }
    $pdf->Output();  //mostrar en pantalla
?>
```

EL error me lo marca en **nombres** ¿esto a que se puede deber?

Answer (score 0):

Al generar tu consulta debe existir una columna **nombre** ya que al utilizar `fetch_assoc()`, asocia eso como index en el row del `while`.

¿Existe ese campo en tu tabla `posts`?